# dynamic framework inside framework in swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, frameworks

I have a framework(inner) with some functions inside. I want to use this framework inside another framework(outer). (both with dynamic mach-O type). and when try to add the second framework(outer) in a project and try to run, result in
Library not loaded: @rpath/
and searching for inner framework and getting "no such file" error.
It seems the search path for the inner framework is incorrect.
Could anyone suggest a solution to fix this issue.